# Interweave a VT unpack with a meta-sequence

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

```
template <int I> struct int_ {};

template < typename ... Pack >
struct thingy
{
    void call()
    {
       f(???);
    }
 };
```

When instantiated it should end up being:

```
struct thingy<int,char,double>
{
    void call()
    {
        f(int, int_<1>(), char, int_<2>(), double, int_<3>());
    }
}
```

What you think, can it be done?  How?

The only thing I can think of is to have overloads for thingy with N different parameters like so:

```
template < typename T0 > struct thingy<T0> { ... };
template < typename T0, typename T1 > struct thingy<T0,T1> { ... };

etc...
```

With a call implementation in each.

Answer (score 5):

> Can it be done

Yes, of course.

> How ?

In several steps.

- You need to be able to create a range of integers
- You need to be able to interleave two sequences

Let us start with the range of integers.

```
template <size_t...>
struct IntegralPack {};

template <size_t A, size_t... N>
IntegralPack<N..., A> push_back(IntegralPack<N...>);

template <size_t A, size_t... N>
IntegralPack<A, N...> push_front(IntegralPack<N...>);

template <size_t L, size_t H>
struct IntegralRangeImpl {
    typedef typename IntegralRangeImpl<L+1, H>::type Base;
    typedef decltype(push_front<L>((Base()))) type;
};

template <size_t X>
struct IntegralRangeImpl<X, X> {
    typedef IntegralPack<> type;
};

template <size_t L, size_t H>
struct IntegralRange {
     static_assert(L <= H, "Incorrect range");
     typedef typename IntegralRangeImpl<L, H>::type type;
};
```

The conversion step is easy enough (thankfully):

```
template <typename...>
struct TypePack {};

template <size_t... N>
TypePack<int_<N>...> to_int(IntegralPack<N...>);
```

So the next difficulty is the merge.

```
template <typename... As, typename... Bs>
TypePack<As..., Bs...> cat(TypePack<As...>, TypePack<Bs...>);

template <typename, typename> struct Interleaver;

template <>
struct Interleaver<TypePack<>, TypePack<>> {
  typedef TypePack<> type;
};

template <typename A0, typename B0, typename... As, typename... Bs>
struct Interleaver<TypePack<A0, As...>, TypePack<B0, Bs...>> {
  typedef typename Interleaver<TypePack<As...>, TypePack<Bs...>>::type Base;
  typedef decltype(cat(TypePack<A0, B0>{}, Base{})) type;
};
```

Putting it altogether:

```
template <typename... Pack>
struct thingy {
    typedef typename IntegralRange<1, sizeof...(Pack) + 1>::type Indexes;
    typedef decltype(to_int(Indexes{})) Ints;
    typedef typename Interleaver<TypePack<Pack...>, Ints>::type Types;

    void call() { this->callImpl(Types{}); }

    template <typename... Ts>
    void callImpl(TypePack<Ts...>) {
        f(Ts{}...);
    }
};
```

Tadaam!

Comment: Nice answer - it would take me an all-nighter to come up with something like that on my own! +1

Comment: Sweet.  I'll have to check it out.  I'll post my own answer that does it without doing it...gets the call done without answering the question that is.  Unfortunately, as I was working on it I ran into other trouble with my underlying type's interface, freaked out for a while, did a shot, and went to bed.

Comment: @CrazyEddie: I'd be glad if you could ping me (write a comment here) once you answered :)

Answer (score 0):

So the way I went about it is a little more specific to what I was actually doing.  Turns out some information I thought was beside the point helped me out.  I think though that a similar technique could be used for any case.

For one thing...in my case "thingy<>" actually has values in it and is passed to the invoker function.  This actually helps a lot.

Also, since the object was to convert the stuff in thingy to serve as induces for another weird thingy, and the ints being passed in were to index the first thingy...the ints end up all being 1 when I do my recursion.  So while what I was after was something like (simplified to remove the second tuple):

```
f(get(my_thingy, idx<1>), get(my_thingy, idx<2>), ...)
```

It turns out the recursion gets rid of idx<2>...idx:

```
template < typename Fun, typename H, typename ... T, typename ... Args >
auto call(Fun f, thingy<H,T...> const& t, Args&& ... args) 
  -> decltype(call(f,static_cast<thingy<T...>const&>(t), get(t,idx<1>), std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{
    return call(f, static_cast<thingy<T...>const&>(t), get(t, idx<1>), args...);
}

template < typename Fun, typename ... Args >
auto call(Fun f, thingy<> const&, Args&& ... args)
   -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I have not been able to fully test thing because the `get` function fails on me for some reason when using const&...kinda pissing me off.  I'm fairly confident that this does the trick though.

If the parameter to idx wasn't always 1 I think that could be forwarded along in a similar fashion.

Comment: `static_cast<thingy<T...>const&>(t)` this seems to imply that you have an inheritance hierarchy going here, which does not match the definition of `thingy` provided in the question: mind editing the new definition into this answer ?